# PHP, Regex replace line breaks in user input only between two reserved charcters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am dealing with a textarea user input which some characters are reserved for example:

```
[ means <h1>
] means </h1>
{ means <p>
} means </p>
```

**Example user input:**

```
[Hello World title]
{hello worlds paragraph
and paragraph continues after line break}
```

**Example system display:**

```
<h1>Hello World title<h1>
<p>hello worlds paragraph<br/>
and paragraph continues after line break</p>
```

---

All the HTML tags are filtered out from user input, and PHP script will replace these characters for the front-end.

I want to use PHP function "nl2br" to replace line breaks with <br/>.

The problem is only the line breaks between `{` and `}` characters should be replaced by `<br />`.

Also I need to consider if user input more than one paragraph using `{}`.

Comment: How are you currently converting `[]` and `{}` to `<h1></h1>` and `<p></p>`, you might be able to fudge it in there.

Comment: $characters = array(
        '['=>'<h1>',
        ']'=>'</h1>',
        '{'=>'<p>',
        '}'=>'</p>',
    );
    foreach ($characters as $k=>$v){
        $text = str_ireplace("$k","$v", $text);
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do both replacements at the same time, using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
<?php

$input="{user input
user input}

newlines that aren't replaced";

function format_paragraph($m){
    return '<p>'.nl2br($m[1]).'</p>';
}

echo preg_replace_callback("/\{(.*)\}/s",format_paragraph,$input);

?>
```

Test the code [here](http://codepad.org/CrxqFESR)

This example will add both the p tags and replace newlines with 
 in one single replacement.

Comment: Either use `.*?` or `[^}]+` for a non-greedy match.